Data loading to a MS Access Junction table from a form
I have a junction table linked to two other tables. This provides a many to many connection.
The two linked tables already have some data, and I can manually put this into the junction table.
But how can I add new data that is entered into one or both of the two tables to be loaded into the junction table in the same record?
Each of the two tables has a primary key that needs to be inserted into the Junction table. Is there a Form setup I can use?
Should I use VBA? How do I ensure each of the two primary keys from the tables get installed into the same Junction table record.
Pictures and/or detailed instructions would help.
Thank you
John Schreiber
SubmarineCOB@outlook.com
I have only set up the junction table with a couple of records for testing.  I am just at my wits end trying to figure out how to proceed.

Simply create a form based on the junction table with two combo boxes that point to the other two linked tables.

Or a form/subform arrangement. Junction table would be in the subform. One of the other two tables would be main form and a combobox on subform to select from third table.

In access you make forms to help with data entry rather than entering data directly in the tables.  It is about ease and efficiency.  For instance, what if someone was assigning starfleet officers to ships.  Its most efficient for the assigner(?) to think in terms of assignments, officers, and ships, but the data is tables of numbers and strings.  The form automates and assists with this translation.
The above was context to explain why, as parfait commented, I usually start setting up data entry for my junction tables with a junction table and some controls in the header but I seldom finish there.
Onto the example:
Access forms have built in functionality to handle Primary and Foreign keys but don't forget to explicitly tell Access about the structure of your table relationships using the relationship tool:

After! specifying the relationship Access knows how to handle inserting the Autonumbers and Foreign keys.  So create a default form from the junction table and add controls to the forms header for each property in the junction table except for the Junction Table Primary Key ShipAssignmentID (it is autonumber).
As I go along I adjust the controls in the header and the details section to show business terms rather than table entries.

At this point use this form to study how access inserts and updates the table.  If the control is bound you can unbind it by deleting the control source and see how the control now does nothing to the selected table row.  The controls in the details section can be unbound as well.  Rebind everything and observe carefully how the foreign keys are being updated and how the autonumber ShipAssignmentID is created.
When you are done continue adjusting the controls to display everything in business terms including deleting the control in the details section that shows the ShipAssignmentID.  ShipAssignmentID is still in the forms record source so sql will work but it is part of how the tables are set up not part of the business the database is representing.


If I was going to continue improving this form I might add buttons to open the forms to add officers or ships.  Under faster data entry, what about when a lot of officers need to be assigned to a new ship.  I could adjust this form or create an almost duplicate form where I replace the Officers combobox in the header with an officers multi-select listbox.  I wish I had done that example as it only adds looping through a listbox.  Instead I add 400 years to every date I enter to make the dates I can enter the quickest more treky.
First unbind all those controls in the header.  We need to do the table changes ourselves as we are doing more.  Instead we will hook up that previously unmentioned assign officers button.
Private Sub cmdAssignOfficer_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("ShipAssignments")
rs.AddNew 'ShipAssignmentsID assigned
rs!OfficerID = Me.cmbOfficerNickName 'default value of cmbOfficerNickName is set up to be OfficerID
rs!ShipID = Me.cmbShipName
rs!AssignmentStart = DateAdd("yyyy", 400, CDate(Me.txtAssignmentStart)) 'make date more treky
rs.Update
Me.Requery 'show changes in the recordsource
End Sub

